# Can't install packages in R anymore: dbus error

Tags: r, dbus, install.packages

Suddenly, I can't install any more packages in R using `install.packages`. For any package I want to install (including random characters), I get the following error message:

```
> install.packages('tensorA')
Error in install.packages : dbus: Call failed: Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 658, in _message_cb    (candidate_method, parent_method) = _method_lookup(self, method_name, interface_name)  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 248, in _method_lookup    raise UnknownMethodException('%s is not a valid method of interface %s' % (method_name, dbus_interface))dbus.exceptions.UnknownMethodException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method: available is not a valid method of interface org.r_project.linux1.PackageManager
```

That's my session info:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3;  LAPACK version 3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2  cli_3.6.1       tools_4.3.2     rstudioapi_0.14
[5] bspm_0.5.1      rlang_1.1.0
```

Any tip appreciated!

Comment: `dbus` is in the package `keyring` , so maybe start by checking the documentation there .    But I'm concerned -- even under Linux,  `install.packages`  so far as I can tell has no reason to invoke `python` , so something is weird -- or else the package `tensorA` has a LOT of external requirements?  Check that out too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that it's `tensorA` causing the trouble, I even get the error message when trying to install a package that doesn't exist. It almost seems as if I have to do a fresh install of Ubuntu :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that `bspm` is installed via `sudo` -- the error is indicative of it not being the case.

The `bspm` [docs](https://cran4linux.github.io/bspm) state

> Then, you should install bspm as a system package to be able to use it as a regular user. Download the latest version from CRAN or GitHub and proceed with the installation (note sudo):
>
> ```
> $ sudo R CMD INSTALL bspm_[version].tar.gz
> ```

The error message is a little confusing, and can happen if you say, upgrade `bspm` via a normal installation and thereby 'drop' the system level aspect.

You can also call the helper function `bspm::shadowed_packages()` to see if you accidentally installed a second copy of `bspm` in the `.libPaths()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip, I could fix the problem. Indeed, I had a second copy of `bspm` installed. I completely removed `bspm`, first the second copy by calling `remove.packages('bsmp')` from R, then the original version via `sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/bspm`. Then I opened `/etc/R/Rprofile.site` as sudo and commented out the line `bspm::enable()`. After installing `bspm` following the guide linked above and rebooting my desktop the problem disappeared.

Comment: Glad to hear. One sometimes needs  `Rscript -e 'bspm::disable(); install.packages(....)` to install from a different repo or version in case the `bspm`-driven search gets in the way.  I hope [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) is proving useful with it too.  Having all of CRAN 'automagically' via `apt` is powerful..

Answer (score 0):

The operation is trying to contact the `bspm` service (which appears to be a helper service that uses the OS package manager – dnf, apt, pacman etc. – to install R packages). This happens to be done via D-Bus, but the error message is not actually related to D-Bus; it comes from `bspm` itself.

The message says that R attempted to call the `available()` function, which doesn't exist in the service. According to Git commit logs, this function was [added in version 0.3.10.1](https://github.com/cran4linux/bspm/commit/8b488f5a0c818d407df61eee90624ed0612da1f8) of bspm.

Use `busctl status org.r_project.linux1.PackageManager` (with or without `--user`, I'm not sure) to find the process (PID and command line) that currently provides this service. It's likely that bspm was upgraded but an old version is still running; kill the process and let it restart automatically.

(It's also possible that you somehow have two versions of bspm – R is trying to use 0.5.1 which expects the `available()` method to be available, but D-Bus is set up to automatically start a much older version.)

Comment: It is actually most likely the _permissions_ rather than the version. See my answer.